# List index out of range with one some data sets?

Tags: python-3.x, list-manipulation

I am trying to code up a numerical clustering tool. Basically, I have a list (here called 'product') that should be transformed from an ascending list to a list that indicates linkage between numbers in the data set. Reading in the data set, removing carriage returns and hyphens works okay, but manipulating the list based on the data set is giving me a problem.

```
# opening file and returning raw data
file = input('Data file: ')
with open(file) as t:
    nums = t.readlines()
    t.close()

print(f'Raw data: {nums}')

# counting pairs in raw data 
count = 0
for i in nums:
    count += 1
print(f'Count of number pairs: {count}')

# removing carriage returns and hyphens    
one = []
for i in nums:
    one.append(i.rsplit())
new = []
for i in one:
    for a in i:
        new.append(a.split('-'))
print(f'Data sets: {new}')

# finding the range of the final list
my_list = []
for i in new:
    for e in i:
        my_list.append(int(e))
ran = max(my_list) + 1

print(f'Range of final list: {ran}')
# setting up the product list
rcount = count-1
product = list(range(ran))
print(f'Unchanged product: {product}')
for i in product:
    for e in range(rcount):
        if product[int(new[e][0])] < product[int(new[e][1])]:
            product[int(new[e][1])] = product[int(new[e][0])]
        else:
            product[int(new[e][0])] = product[int(new[e][1])]

print(f'Resulting product: {product}')
```

I expect the result to be [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 1, 5, 5], but am met with a 'list index out of range' when using a different data set.

the data set used to give the above desired product is as follows: '1-2\n', '2-3\n', '3-4\n', '5-6\n', '7-8\n', '2-10\n', '11-12\n', '5-12\n', '\n'

However, the biggest issue I am facing is using other data sets. If there is not an additional carriage return, as it turns out, I will have the list index out of range error.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite figure out what you're actually trying to do here. What does "indicates linkages" mean, and how does the final output do so? Also, can you show an example of a dataset where it actually fails? And provide the actual exception that you get?

Regardless, your code is massively over-complicated, and cleaning it up a little may also fix your index issue. Using `nums` as from your sample above:

```
# Drop empty elements, split on hyphen, and convert to integers
pairs = [list(map(int, item.split('-'))) for item in nums if item.strip()]

# You don't need a for loop to count a list
count = len(pairs)

# You can get the maximum element with a nested generator expression
largest = max(item for p in pairs for item in p)
```

Also, in your final loop you're iterating over `product` while also modifying it in-place, which tends to not be a good idea. If I had more understanding of what you're trying to achieve I might be able to suggest a better approach.